# What's the difference between '관형사' and '형용사'?

Tags: grammar, difference, adjective

According to Naver dictionary, '[관형사](http://krdic.naver.com/detail.nhn?docid=3719900)' means:

> <언어> 체언 앞에 놓여서, 그 체언의 내용을 자세히 꾸며 주는 품사. 조사도 붙지 않고 어미 활용도 하지 않는데, ‘순
>   살코기’의 ‘순8’과 같은 성상 관형사, ‘저 어린이’의 ‘저4’와 같은 지시 관형사, ‘한 사람’의 ‘한1’과 같은 수
>   관형사 따위가 있다.

and '[형용사](http://krdic.naver.com/detail.nhn?docid=42540000)' means:

> <언어> 사물의 성질이나 상태를 나타내는 품사. 활용할 수 있어 동사와 함께 용언에 속한다.

According to a Korean-English dictionary, '[관형사](http://endic.naver.com/search.nhn?sLn=kr&searchOption=all&query=%EA%B4%80%ED%98%95%EC%82%AC)' is 'determiner', but the examples above don't seem like a determiner in English. What is the real difference between '관형사' and '형용사' in Korean? How can you tell the difference between the two?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

관형사 and 형용사 are different parts of speech (품사)<sup>1</sup>.  Both could be compared to adjectives in English, but some 관형사 like 그 are more similar to English determiners.  But they are distinct parts of speech in Korean.

**관형사** are modifiers which just have a base form; they cannot have any 어미 (verb/adjective endings) added on.  They must precede a noun/pronoun.  Some examples are:

> 모든, 어느, 그, 새 (new), 헌(old/used), 옛, 저런

These cannot really be used as predicates, except by modifying a noun:

> 이거 새 거에요? (Is this new?)

**형용사** are sometimes called adjectives, descriptive verbs or adjectival verbs.  They have predicate forms (ending in -다 for the citation form) and modifier forms (관형사형).

For example: 아름답다 (beautiful) is a 형용사 in predicate form; the usual modifier form (관형사형) is 아름다운.  We can use it thus:

> 아름다운 공주 (beautiful princess)
>
> 공주가 아름다워요 (the princess is beautiful)

Note that 관형사형 is the modifier form of other parts of speech; verbs, nouns and adjectives can all have 관형사형 (관형사 form):

> 어제 **읽던** 책 (the book I was reading yesterday)
>
> **오늘의** 날씨 (today's weather)

<sup>1</sup> According to 한국의 언어 (이익섭, 이상억 & 채완 (1997). 한국의 언어. 서울: 신구문화사), there are 9 품사 in Korean: 명사 (noun), 대명사 (pronoun), 수사 (number), 동사 (verb), 형용사, 관형사, 부사 (adverb), 감탄사 (interjection) and 조사 (noun ending).  There may be competing definitions, however.

Comment: This answer to be updated to talk about the more plentiful 관형사's, which have the ending of -적 (derived from Chinese) (e.g. 간접적 (indirect), 감동적 (touching, moving, stirring), 이상적 (ideal), etc.).